# How to extend my class to accept 64-bit numbers in c++?

Tags: c++

I've implemented a class and I overloaded basic arithmetic operations (+,-,*,/). I'm working on a 32-bit machine so my int is 32-bit(4-byte). I want now to extend this class to accept numbers that are larger then 32-bit, but I am confused how to do that?
My header file looks like below:

```
    using namespace std;

    #ifndef _bignumbers_H
    #define _bignumbers_H

    class bignumbers
    {
        public:
            bignumbers(int _nr){ nr = _nr; }

            //overloaded operators
            friend bignumbers operator+(const bignumbers& _nr1, const bignumbers& _nr2);
            friend bignumbers operator-(const bignumbers& _nr1, const bignumbers& _nr2);
            friend bignumbers operator*(const bignumbers& _nr1, const bignumbers& _nr2);
            friend bignumbers operator/(const bignumbers& _nr1, const bignumbers& _nr2);

            int getNumber() { return nr; }; 
        private:
            int nr;
        protected:
    };

    bignumbers operator+(const bignumbers& nr_1, const bignumbers& nr_2){ 
        return bignumbers(nr_1.nr + nr_2.nr);
    } 
    bignumbers operator-(const bignumbers& nr_1, const bignumbers& nr_2){ 
        return bignumbers(nr_1.nr - nr_2.nr);
    } 
    bignumbers operator*(const bignumbers& nr_1, const bignumbers& nr_2){ 
        return bignumbers(nr_1.nr * nr_2.nr);
    } 
    bignumbers operator/(const bignumbers& nr_1, const bignumbers& nr_2){ 
        return bignumbers(nr_1.nr / nr_2.nr);
    } 

    #endif
```

Then in main.cpp I wrote:

```
int main ()
 {
    // HERE I WANT TO SPECIFY TYPE BIGNUMBER, AND THEN I CAN TYPE
    // NUMBERS WHICH ARE 64 BITS and not 32(int) like here
    // HOW CAN I DO THAT ??????
    int var1 = 0;
    cout<< "Put in first int number: ";
    cin >> var1;

    int var2 = 0;
    cout<< "Put in second int number: ";
    cin >> var2;

    bignumbers NR_1(var1), NR_2(var2);

    bignumbers SUM = NR_1 + NR_2;
    bignumbers DIFFERENCE = NR_1 - NR_2;
    bignumbers PRODUCT = NR_1 * NR_2;
    bignumbers DIVISION = NR_1 / NR_2;

    cout << NR_1.getNumber() << " + " << NR_2.getNumber() << " = " << SUM.getNumber() << endl;
    cout << NR_1.getNumber() << " - " << NR_2.getNumber() << " = " << DIFFERENCE.getNumber() << endl;
    cout << NR_1.getNumber() << " * " << NR_2.getNumber() << " = " << PRODUCT.getNumber() << endl;
    cout << NR_1.getNumber() << " / " << NR_2.getNumber() << " = " << DIVISION.getNumber() << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: no need to yell in ALL CAPS and use multiple punctuation marks (like this!!!!!). You can just use `int64_t` if you want to operate on 64-bit signed integers.

Comment: Your class is already broken because the underlying data storage is no larger than that of your platform's `int` type.

Comment: Sorry for my punctuation and All CAPS (Writing style). Yep @LightnessRacesinOrbit you are right, but can i make a combination maybe I can store value to a string then convert it to 64 bit number from string? Is this available?

Comment: There is _loads_ of material online about how to write a bignum class. Have you read any of it?

Comment: Actually i did a lot of searching before I decided to write the question here! All I got when I searched, were BigInt class which is very complex for what I'm looking for. Anyway, thanks for your help and your time. I will try some solutions as you and others suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Paramagnetic Croissant said, use `int64_t` (or `__int64`, if your compiler does not have `int64_t`). Even though you are on a 32-bit OS, it will work.

If you want to implement it yourself, you can't just store the number as one 32-bit number. What you are doing there is essentially creating a new class to implement a standard 32-bit integer.

You would need to track each number with 2 separate 32-bit integers and implement all of your operators to use both of the 32-bit ints making up 1 64-bit int properly to produce an output set of 2 32-bit ints that represent 1 64-bit int. Then when you consider signed vs unsigned it gets even hairier.

The short of it is, use a provided 64-bit int, like `int64_t`.

If this is homework or something, I'd look at Microsoft's `LARGE_INTEGER` to get a good idea of an interface to use and a way to internally represent the 64-bit integer.

Comment: Thanks for your super-quick answer RyanP and Remy. I will give a try with int64_t and if I can't do anything with it, I will try to use 2 x 32-bits ints to get one 64-bit because that's what I need to do.  It sounds very interesting LARGE_INTEGER from Microsoft too.